# express render called before parameter evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm quite new to nodejs, express and javascript.
I have a code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    const content = fileReader();

    res.render('index', { "content" :  content } );
});
```

fileReader is reading files in for loop using fs.readFileSync so it first read all files and then return one big string.

This string is then passed to view and rendered.

The above code works fine but when I change it to this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { "content" :  fileReader() } );
});
```

It does not work. The page is rendered but the content is empty.

fileReader function:

```
const fileReader = function()
{
    let low = 0;
    let high = 9;

    let content = "";

    for( ; low <= high; low++ )
    {
        if( fs.existsSync( contentDir + "/" + low ) )
        {
            content += fs.readFileSync( contentDir + "/" + low, "utf-8" );
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return content;
}
```

Could someone explain what is going on here? why the render is called before fileReader() finish? shouldn't the function be executed first and calling of render wait for result? Or render and fileReader are called in parallel?

Please explain.

Comment: Can you post the code for the fileReader()?

Comment: Both examples are equal. Are you shure the first one generates the real result?

Comment: @roughcoder added the fileReader

Comment: @Jonasw it reads currently 3 files with content and sends it correctly, I can see the content in the browser, but with the second snippet I can not

Comment: Both are equal. The error is somewhere else, look into the console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use sync functions in nodeJs and i'm pretty sure that's the reason why it renders your page without the content.

Also what you should do is :

```
const fileReader = function()
{
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
     let low = 0;
     let high = 9;

     let content = "";

     for( ; low <= high; low++ )
     {
       fs.readFile( contentDir + "/" + low, "utf-8",(err,data)=>{
           if(err){
               reject(err);
           }
           content += data;
       });
     }
     resolve(content)
   });

}
```

for your filereader and the following for your route :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    fileReader().then((data)=>{
        res.render('index', { "content" :  data } );
     }).catch((error)=>{
          //handle your error
     }); 
 });
```

Comment: if fs.readFile is async then won't be resolve called before the content is filled? Or the code before resolve is executed and finished first? OR promise return reference to content and because you do .then the resolve is called with empty content but the content is then filled as the files are read? Also does this guarantees the order of files to be added to the content? or will (may) it be random? Thanks for your answer but please could you elaborate a bit more

Comment: Sorry for this late answer, i was looking for a better solution and just found this : https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

If you keep scrolling to the "Promises" chapter you can find a way to solve your problem. The process is simple, he wrap the fs.stat function with a promise and then he resolve them all with `Promise.all()`. you can do the same with `fs.readFile()` instead of `fs.stat()`

Comment: Thanks, I was playing with it a bit more and actually come up with that too, but I don't reject the promise on no file but always resolve, the difference is the value. If I understand correctly the first reject, stop processing of the rest promises, so if the first file doesn't exist I will never read the rest. So I have an array of promises and wait for all of them, do resolve even on error with NaN value and then filter the result array and use only the data from fs read, which is then sended as new array to view, this way also the order is guaranteed.